# An interesting variant on the maximum independent set problem.

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, discrete-mathematics

Suppose i have a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|=n$. Furthermore suppose i give you a maximum independent set $\mathcal{I}$ in $G$. Now suppose i obtain a new graph $G'$ from $G$ by removing a single vertex $v \in \mathcal{I}$ from $V$. Now of course $\alpha(G') \in \{|\mathcal{I}|,|\mathcal{I}|-1\}$ but can we say more? Is it an NP-hard to find a maximum independent set in $G'$?

Comment: Have you thought about joining an arbitrary graph $G$ to an independent set of size $k$ by adding in all the cross edges?  That doesn't instantly tell you that it's NP-hard, but it seems like the right thing to look at

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $G$ is obtained from the complete bipartite graph with parts of size $n/2$ by adding some edges in each part. Then a maximum independent set lies in one part or the other, so determining $\alpha(G')$ requires solving the maximum independent set problem in the part disjoint from $\mathcal{I}$. So this is definitely NP-complete.

Answer (score 3):

Following the suggestion in [Ben Barber's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258816/an-interesting-variant-on-the-maximum-independent-set-problem#comment638528_258816), any algorithm for solving your problem (of finding a maximum independent set in $G'$) can be used to find a maximum independent set in any finite graph.

Let G be a graph of order $n.$ For $0\le k\le n$ let $G_k$ be a graph of order $n+k$ obtained by adding to $G$ an independent set $\mathcal I_k$ of $k$ new vertices, and adding edges joining all the vertices in $\mathcal I_k$ to all the vertices of $G.$

Since $\mathcal I_n$ is a maximum independent set in $G_n,$ we can use your algorithm to find a maximum independent set in $G_{n-1}.$ If the maximum independent set that we find in $G_{n-1}$ is $\mathcal I_{n-1},$ we use the algorithm again to find a maximum independent set in $G_{n-2},$ and so on. Eventually we will find a maximum independent set of some $G_{k}$ which is contained in $V(G).$